# Creating two columns without drawing a table

Tags: tables, itemize

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.5cm}

    \usepackage{pifont}
    \usepackage{sectsty}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\scshape}r}
    \frenchspacing
    \sectionfont{%
      \fontfamily{phv}\bfseries
      \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}%
    }
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{document}


\section*{Reviewing activities}
\begin{itemize}
  \item [\ding{228}] Referee for some National and International Research Journals such as
  \begin{itemize}
  \item [\ding{51}] Revista de la Real Academia de Ciencias Exactas, F\'isicas y Naturales. Serie A. Matem\'aticas (published by Springer).
  \item [\ding{51}] Advances in Operator Theory (published by Springer).
  \item [\ding{51}] Czechoslovak Mathematical Journal.
  \item [\ding{51}] Hacettepe Journal of Mathematics and Statistics.
  %\item Reviewer for the journal: Bulletin of the Iranian Mathematical Society (published by Springer).
\item [\ding{51}] Operators and matrices.
\item [\ding{51}] Filomat.
\item [\ding{51}] Open Mathematics.
\item [\ding{51}] Mathematica Slovaca.
\item [\ding{51}] Banach Journal of Mathematical Analysis (published by Springer).
   % \item Reviewer for the journal: Communications of the Korean Mathematical Society.
\item [\ding{51}] Moroccan Journal of Pure and Applied Analysis.
\item [\ding{51}] Miskolc Mathematical Notes.
\end{itemize}
  \item [\ding{228}] Reviewer for Mathematical Reviews/MathSciNet
\end{itemize}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

> I want to organize the items in two columns without drawing the table as this pic shows

[image]

Comment: multicol package and `\begin{multicols}{2}\begin{itemize ...` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following up on @DavidCarlisle's comment: You could employ the [multicol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package to encase the inner `itemize` environment in a two-column `multicols` environment.

I'd further like to suggest that you use the machinery of the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to create bespoke "ding-symbol" itemize-like environments; this will greatly help in decluttering the subsequent code. Furthermore, I'd suspend full justification in the two-column part of the list. Finally, unless it's really important to mention that some journal is "published by Springer", I'd omit that information.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

%% Old code (simplified):
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=1.5cm,top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\pagestyle{empty}

%% New code:
\usepackage{enumitem}
% create a bespoke, two-level itemize-like list environment:
\newlist{dingitemize}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[dingitemize,1]{label=\ding{228},left=0pt,nosep}
\setlist[dingitemize,2]{label=\ding{51}, left=0pt,nosep}

\usepackage{multicol} % for 'multicols' environment
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro

\begin{document}

\section*{Reviewing activities}

\begin{dingitemize}
\item Referee for some national and international research journals, including:
   \begin{multicols}{2} 
   \RaggedRight % suspend full justification
   \begin{dingitemize}
      \item Revista de la Real Academia de Ciencias Exactas, F\'isicas y Naturales, Serie~A Matem\'aticas %(published by Springer)
      \item Advances in Operator Theory %(published by Springer)
      \item Czechoslovak Mathematical Journal
      \item Hacettepe Journal of Mathematics and Statistics
      %\item Reviewer for the journal: Bulletin of the Iranian Mathematical Society %(published by Springer)
      \item Operators and matrices
      \item Filomat
      \item Open Mathematics
      \item Mathematica Slovaca
      \item Banach Journal of Mathematical Analysis %(published by Springer)
      % \item Reviewer for the journal: Communications of the Korean Mathematical Society
      \item Moroccan Journal of Pure and Applied Analysis
      \item Miskolc Mathematical Notes
   \end{dingitemize}
   \end{multicols}
\item Reviewer for Mathematical Reviews\slash MathSciNet
\end{dingitemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just I would like to know what you have added ``\RaggedRight''? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Student -- The macro `\RaggedRight`, which is defined in the `ragged2e` package, suspends full justification of lines and switches to a so-called "ragged-right" (hence the name of the macro) look. I added the `\RaggedRight` instruction because fully-justified narrow lines tend to look not so good.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already use the `tabularx` package, you could place the content in a `tabularx` environment with two `X` type columns. Just separate the columns with `&`.

[image: two columns table]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.5cm}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\scshape}r}
\frenchspacing
\sectionfont{%
    \fontfamily{phv}\bfseries
    \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    
    
\section*{Reviewing activities}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item [\ding{228}] Referee for some National and International Research Journals such as
        \begin{itemize}
            \item [\ding{51}] Revista de la Real Academia de Ciencias Exactas, F\'isicas y Naturales. Serie A. Matem\'aticas (published by Springer).
            \item [\ding{51}] Advances in Operator Theory (published by Springer).
            \item [\ding{51}] Czechoslovak Mathematical Journal.
            \item [\ding{51}] Hacettepe Journal of Mathematics and Statistics.
            %\item Reviewer for the journal: Bulletin of the Iranian Mathematical Society (published by Springer).
            \item [\ding{51}] Operators and matrices.
            \item [\ding{51}] Filomat.
            \item [\ding{51}] Open Mathematics.
            \item [\ding{51}] Mathematica Slovaca.
            \item [\ding{51}] Banach Journal of Mathematical Analysis (published by Springer).
            % \item Reviewer for the journal: Communications of the Korean Mathematical Society.
            \item [\ding{51}] Moroccan Journal of Pure and Applied Analysis.
            \item [\ding{51}] Miskolc Mathematical Notes.
        \end{itemize}
        \item [\ding{228}] Reviewer for Mathematical Reviews/MathSciNet
    \end{itemize} &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item [\ding{228}] Referee for some National and International Research Journals such as
        \begin{itemize}
            \item [\ding{51}] Revista de la Real Academia de Ciencias Exactas, F\'isicas y Naturales. Serie A. Matem\'aticas (published by Springer).
            \item [\ding{51}] Advances in Operator Theory (published by Springer).
            \item [\ding{51}] Czechoslovak Mathematical Journal.
            \item [\ding{51}] Hacettepe Journal of Mathematics and Statistics.
            %\item Reviewer for the journal: Bulletin of the Iranian Mathematical Society (published by Springer).
            \item [\ding{51}] Operators and matrices.
            \item [\ding{51}] Filomat.
            \item [\ding{51}] Open Mathematics.
            \item [\ding{51}] Mathematica Slovaca.
            \item [\ding{51}] Banach Journal of Mathematical Analysis (published by Springer).
            % \item Reviewer for the journal: Communications of the Korean Mathematical Society.
            \item [\ding{51}] Moroccan Journal of Pure and Applied Analysis.
            \item [\ding{51}] Miskolc Mathematical Notes.
        \end{itemize}
        \item [\ding{228}] Reviewer for Mathematical Reviews/MathSciNet
    \end{itemize}
\end{tabularx}
    
\end{document}
```

However, this won't flow automatically. You can use `multicol` package for that, as  David suggested in his comment.

Comment: Is there a way to distribute the list items automatically across the two columns?

Comment: @Mico not easily possible when using `tabular` environment i think. I also slighty misunderstood the question. +1 for your very nice answer